# Vagrant NFS share doesn't show updated file if size doesn't change

Tags: nfs, virtualbox, cache, arch-linux, vagrant

When mounting /vagrant over NFS, a changed file on the host is not refresh on the guest if the size doesn't changes. Quick update/typo are not immediately reflected unless I make enough modification for the size to be different.

I've tried to set lookupcache=none but apart from making everything slower, nothing change.

I'm using OSX ML as host and Arch Linux as guest. NFS is v3 (because of OSX).

Comment: you need file's mtime to be changed to trigger NFS client to re-read cached blocks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This was bugging me for months, and I finally found a fix, if you're using Sublime Text (I'm on ST3). Check to see if it's using atomic saves — they were causing this issue for me.

To your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file, (*Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings- User*) add this:

```
{
    "atomic_save": false
}
```

This fixed the cached file-size NFS issue for us. Still unsure whether the root issue is in the OS X NFS daemon or the Ubuntu client (my money's on OS X).

Comment: I'll accept your answer as we found the same fix but I forgot to edit/answer the question. Thanks

Comment: This is an important piece of info. One of our developers noticed that changing a digit in code wasn't reflected on his vagrant site (same file size). This is a pretty bad bug. Thanks for sharing this solution.

Comment: This worked instantly. You can also add it to just your project config file under "settings" if you don't want to adjust how Sublime saves files in non-vagrant projects.

Comment: I suspect this would have taken me hours, days, weeks, months, or years to track down.  Thank you Andy!!

Comment: You just saved me like a GAZILLION of cut content/save/refresh/paste/save/refresh...  I buy you a beer.

Comment: Not using sublime text 3, seeing this issue anyway (sublime text 2)

Comment: This was hard to debug @Andy, well done buddy

Answer (score 0):

### VIM users

@andy has done it all, had the same problem using VIM, simply use:

```
:set nobackup
```